# How can I share a particular Google Drive folder with my Slack channels to be able to search in the documents from it?

Tags: google-drive, slack

There is a Google Drive integration with Slack, but:

- in order to search you have to upload all your documents from Drive to Slack
- you have to provide full access to your Google Drive documents and it seems excessive for my case

Are there any other solutions for it?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it seems that the official app from Slack has those limitations and doesn't provide the functionality you're looking for.

This is why we, at Memonia (disclaimer: I’m a co-founder of Memonia), have implemented own integration Slack with Google Drive.
It completely meets your requirements and also provides some additional important features like semantic search in your documents in Google Drive folders.
You can read how to integrate your Google Drive and Slack [here](https://memonia.com/integrations/google-drive).